# Can I gain karma from the Legion by killing off the Mojave Outpost?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

So I want to join the Legion. The NCR is constantly sending rangers after me. I have a Legionary assassin chest plate, and helmet. I also have a Super Sledgehammer. If I go to the Mojave Outpost with these equipped and slaughter everybody, will I be on good terms with the Legion? If not, how do I join them and become accepted there?

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need to wear Legion gear to become excepted by the Legion. When wearing faction armor (such as Legion gear or NCR uniforms) members of that faction will not react hostile towards you, no matter how your relation with them is. So, if you make it to become a Legion member, you'll be an enemy to the NCR. Wearing NCT gear then will prevent them from attacking you on sight.

As for how to join the Legion, continue on your path of getting negative karma. At some point of the main quest line, you will be invited to meet with the Caesar no matter your current affiliations. From then on, just follow the associated quests.